# PowerShell Select-String to look for latest log-file entries

Tags: powershell

Let me be brief here:

I have a couple of machines in AD which I need to check frequently. I am the newcomer to PowerShell and looking for a working way to make it happen.

What needs to be checked? Certain file on remote system, lets call it File1.log (its name is the same in every machine). The file contains numerous lines as follows:

15.10.2013 23:38:54|FA OK 98.9 USD

I need to know how many entries like above for past 2 hours or 24 hours depending on the time of check. ("FA OK" as expression works fine) and get the amount on the last line.

What I already managed to do:
Using $checktime2 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-2).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH") [to match the formating]. The script just generates empty file, despite correct entries in the test file... The code looks awful, but I had no other idea how to check for different hours. It seems to me that AddHours() doesn't accept the variable in brackets or I just don't know how to set it up. Question here - Google advised me that Select-String could accept multiple different values (with OR, not AND logical operator). I am not sure what is wrong here and how to move on. Script works and doesn't report errors. Any feedback on how to make this script work or at least clean it up are very welcome. Thanks in advance!

```
$title = "Check"
$message = "2 or 24 hours back?"
$checktime0 = (Get-Date).AddHours(0).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime1 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime2 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-2).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime3 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-3).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime4 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-4).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime5 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-5).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime6 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-6).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime7 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-7).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime8 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-8).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime9 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-9).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime10 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-10).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime11 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-11).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime12 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-12).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime13 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-13).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime14 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-14).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime15 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-15).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime16 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-16).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime17 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-17).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime18 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-18).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime19 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-19).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime20 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-20).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime21 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-21).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime22 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-22).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime23 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-23).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$checktime24 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-24).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$2 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&A", `
"Check for 2 hours back"
$24 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&B", `
"Check for 24 hours back"
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($2, $24)

$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0)

switch ($result){ 
0   {Get-Content File1.log | Select-String '($checktime2|$checktime1|$checktime0)' | Select-String "FA OK" |  measure-object -line | out-file OPTcheck.txt -Append
Get-Content File1.xjou | Select-String '($checktime2|$checktime1|$checktime0)' | Select-String "FA OK" | select -Last 1 | out-file OPTcheck.txt -Append
}
1   {Get-Content File1.log| Select-String '($checktime24|$checktime23|$checktime22|$checktime21|$checktime20|$checktime19|$checktime18|$checktime17|$checktime16|$checktime15|$checktime14|$checktime13|$checktime12|$checktime11|$checktime10|$checktime9|$checktime8|$checktime7|$checktime6|$checktime5|$checktime4|$checktime3|$checktime2|$checktime1|$checktime0)' | Select-String "FA OK" |  measure-object -line | out-file OPTcheck.txt -Append
Get-Content File1.log | Select-String $checktime24 | Select-String "FA OK" | select -Last 1 | out-file OPTcheck.txt -Append
}
default {Get-Credential} //used to catch the error in switch
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this running more or less as I desired.

Below the answer:

Currently I have like 15 network paths to check for latest update.

```
$Path1 = "\\path-to-the-jou-file-for-2h-check\joufile.jou"
$Path2 = "\\path-to-the-jou-file-for-24h-check\joufile.jou"
```

I defined a 2h and 24h Get-Date aliases. For my needs, I had to check $Path2 file for entries from yesterday, and $path1 to be checked for current hour, last hour and 2 hours ago.

```
$npath = path-to-my-output-file
$date24 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-24).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
$date2 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-2).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$date1 = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
$date0 = (Get-Date).AddHours(0).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH")
```

yes, I know this is overkill, I did add "AddHours(0)" for cosmetics :-) As you see, I translate the output value to the desired formatting so that I can use it for -pattern later on.

For each object that is checked for 2h until now. As you see, I had to use the -pattern parameter to match multiple values in "OR" logic statement:

```
Get-Content $Path1| Select-String -Pattern $date2, $date1, $date0 | Select-String "FA OK" | Measure-Object -line | out-file $npath -Append
Get-Content $Path1 | Select-String -Pattern $date2, $date1, $date0 | Select-String "FA  OK" | Select -last 1 | out-file $npath -Append
Get-Content $1076 | Select-String -Pattern $date2, $date1, $date0 | Select-String "Status now" | Select -last 1 | out-file $npath -Append
```

The difference for 24h timeframe was that I just modify the .ToString value so that it changes the day in log file entry to look for. The problem occurs when the log rolls over, but it happens like once in 2 months so not much of an issue. Could be worth implementing if the script is to be perfect, but it does its job.

I would like to thank you who have taken a look on this matter and provided some input, this was a great help to make first steps in PowerShell that actually do something time-saving. :-)

Thank you!

Koliat

Answer (score 2):

Begin from the begining :

```
$line = "15.10.2013 23:38:54|FA OK 98.9 USD"
$adate= [datetime]::ParseExact(($line.Split('|')[0]),"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",$null)
```

Then you can check if a date is between two dates using :

```
($adate -le ([datetime]::Now).AddHours(-1) -and $adate -gt ([datetime]::Now).AddHours(-2))
```

After that you just need a `if` structure.

Comment: I think that is exactly what I have been looking for! I will give it a try soon and come back with results. Only a couple of days playing around with PS and it doesnt cease to amaze me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the date is in a proper format for your locale perhaps the following code can be of help ? You can run it like this:

```
Check for entries two hours back or newer:

PS1> .\Get-File1.ps1 -Path \\srver\share\file1.log -Two

or check for entries twentyfour hours back or newer

PS1> .\Get-File1.ps1 -Path \\srver\share\file1.log -Twenty   

or check since a specified time back

PS1> .\Get-File1.ps1 -Path \\srver\share\file1.log -Since "15.10.2013 05:05"
```

Below is the code

```
# Get-File1.ps1
#
param([string] $Path, [DateTime] $Since, [switch] $Two, [switch] $TwentyFour);

if ($Two) {
   $Since = $(Get-Date).AddHours(-2);
}
if ($TwentyFour) {
   $Since = $(Get-Date).AddHours(-24);
}   

gc $Path | %{
   $sDate, $status = $_.Split('|');
   $date = Get-Date $sDate;
   if ($date -ge $Since -and $Status -match "^FA OK" ) {
      $_;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps
/fridden